# What should I do before changing graphics card?

Tags: graphics

I'm thinking about buying a new graphic card.
What should I do before removing the old one, other than removing proprietary drivers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like Oli's answer. :)

The only thing I might add if your paranoid about picking a new card and want to be extra cautious would be to check the [Ubuntu hardware catalog for video compatibility](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/category/VIDEO) with your specific card choice.

Answer (score 19):

### Have a cup of tea.

But seriously, that's about all you want to do and you don't even need to do that before you rip it out.

Any old-config issues can be resolved fairly swiftly when the new graphics card is in. If you have issues,

- Get to a terminal any way you can (login if it boots to terminal, or try a TTY via <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>, or if all else fails, hold shift on reboot and enter the recovery console.
- Remove old driver packages
- Nuke `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` from lower orbit.

These are things you *can* do before changing but it makes very little difference.

Comment: Oh ok, so I should not worry too much right?

Comment: Nope. You need not to worry. This is one of the things Linux does a hell of a lot better than Windows ;)

Comment: I don't think so. I'd even say postponing the changes might be better. If your new card is DOA (happens sometimes) you won't have lost your old configuration.

Comment: +1 - I agree. Do as little as possible in case the new card is DOA. It happens when you least expect it!

Comment: sorry what DOA means?

Comment: Dead On Arrival. A card that needs sending back instantly because it's broken when you get it.

Comment: @psylockeer: Dead on arrival

Comment: Oh...that would suck...happened with a motherboard once...